# A mouseclick every 15 seconds

Tags: windows, macros

I want to create a macro that fires a right click every 15 seconds (30 clicks in total.
What kind of software would you recommand for a macro like that?

Comment: I have to ask: Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**AutoHotkey**](http://autohotkey.com) solution:

```
Loop 30
{
    Send {LButton}
    Sleep, 15000
}
```

If this task needs to be done in a browser, and your browser happens to be Firefox, check out the [**iMacros**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863) add-on.

Comment: It's 15000 instead of 15 because it measures milliseconds but then it works brilliantly.

Comment: Whoops went a little too fast. Fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/ may help.

Answer (score -1):

Python3 with Pyautoigui module. The PyautoGui module has its own website explaining how you can do all of that and more. Its very useful. Just go through the category **"Mouse control and functions".**

**https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/**